# Display function arguments in echo area?

Tags: programming

Is there a package to let emacs display the parameters of a function while typing?

For example, if I were to start typing `printf(` in C, I would like it to display the format taken from man pages, kinda like auto-completion, but without actually putting in any text.

Answer (score 7):

[`eldoc-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc) does precisely this.  From the wiki page:

> A very simple but effective thing, eldoc-mode is a MinorMode which shows you, in the echo area, the argument list of the function call you are currently writing. Very handy. By NoahFriedman. Part of Emacs.
>
> ElDoc works for EmacsLisp and certain other language modes that implement support for ElDoc. These include

- CEldocMode – for C, by grepping cpp
- CPerlMode – for Perl
- css-eldoc – for css-mode, available on melpa, see https://github.com/zenozeng/css-eldoc
- EshellElDoc – for Eshell
- EukleidesMode – for Eukleides plane geometry language
- PythonMode (the python.el one) – but only in Emacs 22, or using an Emacs 21 back-port
- SemanticBovinator – tools using that system
- TaclMode – Tandem/NSK/Guardian
- TalMode – Tandem/NSK/Guardian
- Org-mode